# Optimizing weights to improve linear regression

Tags: python, neural-network, regression

I want to use a neural network to optimize an energy function to improve regression with rmsd. My energy function has 16 terms and I want to optimize the weights before summing it.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/fit-data-with-a-neural-network.html has an example and my problem is something similar but I want to implement it in python.

Can someone please give me any pointers to where I can find similar examples/what modules I should use?

Comment: I would suggest looking at pybrain and sklearn. They might be of help to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also recommend pybrain. [pybrain.tools.neuralnets.NNregression](http://pybrain.org/docs/api/tools.html#pybrain.tools.neuralnets.NNregression) is a tool that will help you in regression. [Here](http://fastml.com/pybrain-a-simple-neural-networks-library-in-python/) is an example that will help you get started.